# phpMyAdmin cannot save grid editing modifications

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm trying to use grid editing, when I double-click on a cell it allows editing but if I modify the content there is no way to leave the editor, unless I undo my modifications or use escape.
I spent ages looking for a solution on the net, but it seems to work for anybody else by using Enter or clicking somewhere else, but not for me.

So I checked the box to save at once, and then I was able to leave the editor, but clicking on the Save button does not save anything.

I can with no problem modify data by checking the box in front, but not with grid-editing.

It would really make my life easier, so if anyone can help it would be great!!!

I have the latest version of phpMyAdmin (4.0.10) but it was the same with an older version. I use Xampp.

Comment: Does it happen on any table/column or just on a specific column?

Comment: On any table and column.

Comment: What happens if you use the same browser, but connect to http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/?pma_username=root ?

Comment: It works! and there is something different, I get Modify, Copy, Paste just after the checkbox for each row. I don't have that in my base.

Comment: Which XAMPP version are you using?

Comment: it seems to be 1.8.1 - control panel v3.1.0 3.1.0

Comment: is there a work around?